# Large array of 'int' type needs to be passed to a generic array & collections

Tags: java, arrays, generics, int, primitive-types

I am generating a large arrays(size>1000) with elements of `int` type, from a function. I need to pass this array to a generic type array but since the generic type  array doesnt accept arrays of primitive type, I am unable to do so.

I fear to use the **`Integer`** type array since it will be costly, in terms of creation, performance, space used(an array of 12 byte objects) when doing so for a large size arrays. More it will create immutable  **`Integer`** s when I need to perform some addition operations on the array elements.

What would be the best way to go with ?

**EDIT** Just to remove some confusions around, I need to pass int[] to a method of signature type: `void setKeys(K... keys)`.

Comment: @Marcos Can you give some example code to clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: i think he has a method like public void <T extends Object> processArray(T[] t) but can't use ints with it, of course.

Comment: I'd like to know more about what you're passing it to. If it's like MeBigFatGuy's example, you're stuck. But maybe the API you're calling takes an Iterable or Iterator -- if so, you could implement that on top of int[] without actually materializing all the Integers at the same time. Or maybe you could pass your array in a series of smaller calls.

Comment: I want to pass an `int[]` to this function: `public Query<K> setKeys(K... keys);`

Comment: Well, then all the values have to be `Integer` at the time of the call.

Comment: also neccesarily in the case when I have `public Query<K> setKeys(K[] keys);` right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to pass an `int[]` to this function: `public Query<K> setKeys(K... keys);`

I assume that you mean that `int[]` should be the set of keys ... not just one key.

That is impossible.  The type parameters of a generic type have to be reference types.  Your use-case requires `K` to be a `int`.

You have two choices:

- use `Integer` (or a mutable `int` holder class) and pay the performance penalty, or
- forgo the use of generics and change the signature of that method.

---

Incidentally, the `Integer` class keeps a cache of `Integer` objects for small `int` values.  If you create your objects using `Integer.valueOf(int)` there's a good chance that you will get a reference to an pre-existing object.  (Of course, this only works because `Integer` objects are immutable.)

Comment: **forego the use of generics and change the signature of that method.** : unfortunately that is not in my hands, that is from an external library

Comment: @Marcos - well, there's your answer.  You **have to** use Integer or a mutable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

If your arrays are on the order of 1000 (or even 10,000 or 100,000) elements, the cost difference in terms of memory and performance probably wouldn't be noticeable unless you're processing the arrays thousands of times each. Write the code with Integer and optimize later if you have performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you're *that* concerned about performance, you could write a simple class that wraps a public `int`, thus meaning you can make your call and still mutate it as needed. Having said that, I do agree that you want to make absolute sure you need this performance improvement before doing it.

Comment: E.g. `MutableInt` from Apache Commons :)

Answer (score 0):

If you actually *do* need to worry about the performance implications of boxing/unboxing integers, you could consider [GNU Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/), specifically their `TIntArrayList`.  It lets you mimic the functionality of an `ArrayList<Integer>` while being backed by primitives.  That said, I'm not certain you need this, and I'm not certain this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: good idea but it won't work if he needs to pass it to a function that takes `K[]`, as he says in his comments

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the integers permanently boxed, you could pass in the result of `Ints.asList()` from the Google Collections library ([http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList%28int...%29)), which would be a `List<Integer>` backed by the array.  The values will get boxed as they're accessed, so this only makes sense if the values are not being accessed lots of times.

Comment: As @newacct pointed out for some other answer: good idea but it won't work if he needs to pass it to a function that takes `K[]`, as he says in his comments